# google maps change Icon of marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to change the marker icon and put my own icon with the the following code but insted of the icon nothing appears. Any suggestions please?

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    icon: 'c:\green.jpg'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place your image (green.jpg) inside a folder that is accessible by your program. Put it inside WAR folder for example. If you just have an HTML,PHP,... page, then put the image in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

The icon value is expected to be a URI, so you probably need to pass it a file URI in this case.

```
file:///C:/green.jpg
```

Obviously if you're going to use this on the web then you will need to use a URL of something that is served by a web server, rather than an image file on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setIcon() function. Something like 
marker.setIcon("iconfile")

More information about this function here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Search for: "setIcon(icon:string|MarkerImage)"

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the relative path to the file:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    icon: 'img/markers/brown_MarkerE.png'
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the protocol to use, in your case the `file://` [file transfer protocol](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://c:/green.jpg'
});
```

Note: You have to store the image on your webserver to make it accessible to everyone. That way only user's with an image "grren.jpg" on there `C` partition will see the icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
here is the full document for that with example :
https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers

you can also use this code:

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    icon: 'your_img.png'
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sir i add code also but for more details user can view its link for more better understanding about that

Comment: May be his(user) icon path is not correct "C:\green.jpg" . I think error in this line

Comment: I see the difference now. It would be helpful to make that explicit.